# test if name is already used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord, if-statement

Is there a possibility to test if there already is an element with the same name?

Let's assume I have an array, like this:
`lregion=["de", "eu", "us", "it"]`

I want to put them in my Table with this script, and then, if there already is an element called "eu" it should not be created again.

```
    lregion.each do |x| 
      if      #this "actually" should test, if there is already a country with this countrycode
        Country.create(countrycode: x)                                              #creates Country
      end
    end
```

It's important to do it like this, because I'm using this script in my seeds file, and can't just use `uniqueness: true` in my model, because it would make the seeds.rb crash.

Does anyone have an Idea for my problem?

Comment: Either validate uniqueness and rescue the error or use first_or_create

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd use the `find_or_create`:

```
<% lregion.each do |x| %>
   <% Country.find_or_create_by(countrycode: x.country_code) %>
<% end %>
```

This will search if a `country_code` is already registered, if it's not, then it will create a new one.

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks! But I realised, that it totaly works with validates uniqueness.
But yours is very helpful to! I need this for automatically creating many to many relationships. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped :) I figured it'd work with validate uniqueness, but you mentioned that it'd mess something else up. :)

Answer (score 0):

My previous statement

> It's important to do it like this, because I'm using this script in my seeds file, and can't just use uniqueness: true in my model, because it would make the seeds.rb crash.

Was wrong. I could easily use this!